# Installing Gradle in Windows

Tags: gradle

I am trying to install gradle in my computer (Windows10) after trying to run gradlew.exe after refactoring an sdk that i have.
Already downloaded the last distribution (extracted it under C:/Gradle). 
 Then added it to the path in system variables(C:\Gradle\gradle-4.10.2\bin).
I tried to check Gradle version like the example below and thats what happened.
**PS**: I already installed JDK (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1) and added it to the path in system variables as well.

```
C:\>gradle -v

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or  --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Try running "echo %path%" from a command window and confirm that the path to your gradle bin is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Gradle may not yet support Java 11 (see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4591). Try with another, earlier version of the JDK.